# test fails : matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I've spent the whole day trying to find out where this error might be coming from, but in vain.
My test function is the following:

```py
def test_match_data_while_updating(self):
    # TST N.1 : Match is live
    # -------     
    match_updated_data1 = {
        'match': {
            'id': 1,
            'status': 'not_started',
        },
    }
    match1 = Match.objects.get(id=1)
    request = self.__class__.factory.put('', match_updated_data1, format='json')        
    add_authentication_to_request(request, is_staff=True)
    response = update_match_video(request)
    self.assertEqual(Match.objects.get(id=1).status,'live')
```

And this the relevant part of the function I am testing:

```py
def update_match_video(request):
    if not request.data.get('match').get('id'):
        return JsonResponse({}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    match_id = valid_data_or_error(request.data, method='PUT')['match_data']['id']

    try:
        match = Match.objects.get(id = match_id)
        db_match_status = match.status

        if db_match_status == 'live':
            valid_data_or_error(request.data, method='PUT')['match_data']['status'] = 'live'
        elif db_match_status == 'closed':
            valid_data_or_error(request.data, method='PUT')['match_data']['status'] = 'closed'
    except:
        print('Match does not exist')
```

When I use the command:

```
$ python server/manage.py test --settings=skill.settings_test api.views.tests.test_views.ViewsTestCase
```

to run all the test functions that the file /views/tests/test_views  contain (this file contains only one class which is ViewsTestCase with many tests) all the tests succeed, but when I run all my tests that are located in folder /api/views using:

```
$ python server/manage.py test --settings=skill.settings_test api.views
```

I get the following error:

> ### ERROR: test_match_data_while_updating (api.views.tests.test_views.ViewsTestCase)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/yosra/Bureau/app/master/server/api/views/tests/test_views.py", line 226, in test_match_data_while_updating
>       match1 = Match.objects.get(id=1)
>
> File "/home/yosra/Bureau/app/master/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/yosra/Bureau/app/master/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
>       self.model._meta.object_name
>
> api.models.match.Match.DoesNotExist: Match matching query does not exist.

my test database is not empty, and it contains a match instance with id=1. Also there isn't a test function that deletes this element from my database. Can anyone please give me an indication of where this might be coming from?

I appreciate your help

Comment: Why do you say the test database is not empty? How did you populate it? Django tests always start from an empty db.

Comment: yes I mean That it is populated, I have a file populate_db.py that does that for me and a bunch of text files that contain the data

Comment: You are running your tests with two different settings `skill.settings_test` and `skillcorner.settings_test`. Maybe has something to do...

Comment: I've just updated my post, no it's not about the settings, Thanks!